# How to capture ID value of modal open to edit item?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I'm trying to get a value of 'id' from a modal open onClick(). I've assigned `value={this.props.sightings.id` but does not come up in `event.target.value`.

I've tried to find the value with a debugger and I can see it in the below format but don't know how to access it.

This is the semantic-ui-modal component functionality:

```
<Modal
  trigger={
    <Icon
      name="camera retro"
      value={this.props.sighting.id}
      size="big"
      value={this.props.sighting.id}
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
      onClick={this.handleOpen}
    />
  }
  open={this.state.modalOpen}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
  basic
  size="small"
>
```

This is the click handler:

```
handleOpen = (e) => {
  console.log(e)
  this.setState({ modalOpen: true, })
}
```

This is the result in console:

```
<i
  value="7"
  aria-hidden="true"
  class="camera retro big icon"
  style="flex: 1 1 0%; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"
/>
```

I would like to get the value from `<i value="7"` or perhaps 
an other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this?

```
<Modal
  trigger={
    <Icon
      name="camera retro"
      value={this.props.sighting.id}
      size="big"
      value={this.props.sighting.id}
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}
      onClick={() => this.handleOpen(this.props.sighting.id)}
    />
  }
  open={this.state.modalOpen}
  onClose={this.handleClose}
  basic
  size="small"
>

handleOpen = (yourID) => {
  console.log(yourID)
  this.setState({ modalOpen: true, })
}
```

just pass it to the function, if i've understood your problem...

**EDIT**

if you need to use state instead props, you can copy the value in the constructor eg:

```
constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = { myID : this.props.sighting.id}
}
```

than use `this.state.myID` instead `this.props.sighting.id`

Comment: I should also add that to make this work, you need to set the 'ID' to state before the 'modalOpen'.

Comment: you can do it in the constructor i'll add it in the answer